# Hide Duplicate Rows in Core Data Driven UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a Core Data entity that has two name attributes and several other numeric attributes. The sort is on the numeric attributes first and last on the name attributes. Data is coming from multiple sources and so it is possible to get duplicate rows where the names are switched in order. i.e. row 1 has names Bill and Ed, where row 2 has names Ed and Bill. The rows are identical, except for the fact that the order of the names is switched.

I was hoping that there might be a way to 'hide' the duplicate rows in the table view, but since the row count is coming from the fetchedresults controller, I can't see how that would work.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Jim

Comment: See http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/108730-nspredicate-only-one-item-of-each.html for discussion of a possible way to do this with a fetchRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to create an array containing all the data you actually want to display. You can assign your first source to the array and for the other ones you first verify that the item doesn't exist before adding it. If you know how the duplicates can be presented then you can write the necessary conditions that need to be passed before adding it to the array.